# How to make "lists" or "vectors" of data frames

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

**The short story about what I need**:  I have read in a CSV file, and I want to take some of the columns and store them into variables as their own data frame, and then store the variables into a list.  However, when I use `c()` to do this, it just puts all the data in a flat vector.  Is there a way to have a list of data frames?

**The longer story**: I have read in a CSV file, suppose it looks like this

```
,"Date","px high","px low","px last",,,,"Date","px high","px low","px last"
"eur curncy",03/Jan/2000,1.03,1.01,1.02,,,"gbp curncy",03/Jan/2000,1.64,1.61,1.64
,1/4/2000,1.03,1.02,1.03,,,,1/4/2000,1.64,1.63,1.64
,1/5/2000,1.04,1.03,1.03,,,,1/5/2000,1.65,1.64,"#N/A N/A"
,1/6/2000,1.04,1.03,1.03,,,,1/7/2000,1.65,1.64,1.65
```

When I store the read CSV file and print the variable it looks like

```
            Date        px.high    px.low    px.last    Date.1       px.high.1    px.low    px.last
eur curncy  03/Jan/2000 1.03       1.02      1.03       03/Jan/2000  1.64         1.63      1.64
            1/4/2000    1.03       1.02      1.03       1/4/2000     1.64         1.63      1.64
... etc.
```

I have shaved off a lot of the data for this example to avoid clutter, but there are many more rows and columns of this data.  Along the columns they repeat in these groups each with a date, px high, etc.  Along the rows you more or less get the same as in the last couple rows shown above.

I ultimately want to go into each group of data, segment it into months, compute the average values for each month in each column, and throw away the daily information, and then make a bar chart for each group.  However, I have the following problems that I need to solve:

1. The first row of dates are in a different format from the other rows.  All the rows after the first row are in the same format.  I can pretty well fix this myself by reading in the data as

`cur <- read.csv('C:\\file.csv', stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

and then looping over the columns, assigning in the right places

`cur[1,col] <- as.character(as.date(cur[1,col], format='%d/%b/%Y'))`

I can then format the rest of the date entries by looping over rows and then columns and basically do the same thing again.

2. Some of the entries in the CSV file contain the string "#N/A N/A" which I've found will force R to read every other entry in that column as a string, so that I can no longer perform arithmetic on the objects.  I'm fine with just throwing away those rows of data that have this on them, but even when doing so the columns remain strings.  Also, if I throw the row away from one of these groups, I throw away the whole row for all of the rest of the data, which I don't want to do.

The arithmetic problem is easy to solve, when I do the arithmetic I just convert everything to a numeric.  It might be inefficient but it seems to have worked well enough.  But the issue of all of these rows being together in the same data frame so that if I throw away one row I also throw away all other data on that row--and sometimes the dates of the groups don't match.  So if I throw away a row that has an "#N/A N/A" on it for one date, I'll be throwing away other dates for other groups, which I don't want.  Hence the best solution I can think of is to split the groups into their own data frames and treat them somewhat separately.

3. Some of the data have mis-matching dates.  I want to basically throw away any date from any one of these groups of data, if that date is not shared by all the data.  But again I only want to do this for the same date in all groups--I can't just delete a row because again that row may correspond to one date in one group but another date in another group.  So again it seems like splitting the groups is the thing to do.

But if anyone thinks there's a better way to go, let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question about lists, yes, you can store data frames in lists:

```
l <- list(dat1, dat2, dat3, etc.)
```

If you have odd `NA` values, (999, -1, -11, #N/A, etc), you can use `na.strings` to catch those and keep your columns as numerics:

```
(dat <- read.csv(header = TRUE, na.strings = c('#N/A N/A'),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                text="Date,px high,px low,px last,
03/Jan/2000,1.03,1.01,1.02,
03/Jan/2000,1.64,1.61,1.64,
1/4/2000,1.03,1.02,1.03,
1/4/2000,1.64,1.63,1.64,
1/5/2000,1.04,1.03,1.03,
1/5/2000,1.65,1.64,#N/A N/A,
1/6/2000,1.04,1.03,1.03,
1/7/2000,1.65,1.64,1.65")[1:4])

#          Date px.high px.low px.last
# 1 03/Jan/2000    1.03   1.01    1.02
# 2 03/Jan/2000    1.64   1.61    1.64
# 3    1/4/2000    1.03   1.02    1.03
# 4    1/4/2000    1.64   1.63    1.64
# 5    1/5/2000    1.04   1.03    1.03
# 6    1/5/2000    1.65   1.64      NA
# 7    1/6/2000    1.04   1.03    1.03
# 8    1/7/2000    1.65   1.64    1.65
```

Like you said, there is mixed formatting with the dates, so I use this crude function to check which format is used and tell R the proper one to use:

```
f_dat <- function(x)
  as.Date(x, format = ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(gsub('/','',x))),
                             '%d/%b/%Y', '%d/%m/%Y'))


## and format the dates:

(dat <- within(dat, {
  Date <- f_dat(Date)
}))

#         Date px.high px.low px.last
# 1 2000-01-03    1.03   1.01    1.02
# 2 2000-01-03    1.64   1.61    1.64
# 3 2000-04-01    1.03   1.02    1.03
# 4 2000-04-01    1.64   1.63    1.64
# 5 2000-05-01    1.04   1.03    1.03
# 6 2000-05-01    1.65   1.64      NA
# 7 2000-06-01    1.04   1.03    1.03
# 8 2000-07-01    1.65   1.64    1.65
```

EDIT

```
dat <- read.csv(header = TRUE, na.strings = c('#N/A N/A'),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                text=",Date,px high,px low,px last,,,,Date,px high,px low,px last
eur curncy,03/Jan/2000,1.03,1.01,1.02,,,gbp curncy,03/Jan/2000,1.64,1.61,1.64
,1/4/2000,1.03,1.02,1.03,,,,1/4/2000,1.64,1.63,1.64
,1/5/2000,1.04,1.03,1.03,,,,1/5/2000,1.65,1.64,#N/A N/A
,1/6/2000,1.04,1.03,1.03,,,,1/7/2000,1.65,1.64,1.65")


#            X        Date px.high px.low px.last X.1 X.2        X.3      Date.1 px.high.1 px.low.1 px.last.1
# 1 eur curncy 03/Jan/2000    1.03   1.01    1.02  NA  NA gbp curncy 03/Jan/2000      1.64     1.61      1.64
# 2               1/4/2000    1.03   1.02    1.03  NA  NA               1/4/2000      1.64     1.63      1.64
# 3               1/5/2000    1.04   1.03    1.03  NA  NA               1/5/2000      1.65     1.64        NA
# 4               1/6/2000    1.04   1.03    1.03  NA  NA               1/7/2000      1.65     1.64      1.65


f_dat <- function(x)
  as.Date(x, format = ifelse(is.na(as.numeric(gsub('/','',x))),
                             '%d/%b/%Y', '%d/%m/%Y'))

(dat <- within(dat, {
  Date <- f_dat(Date)
  Date.1 <- f_dat(Date.1)
}))

#            X       Date px.high px.low px.last X.1 X.2        X.3     Date.1 px.high.1 px.low.1 px.last.1
# 1 eur curncy 2000-01-03    1.03   1.01    1.02  NA  NA gbp curncy 2000-01-03      1.64     1.61      1.64
# 2            2000-04-01    1.03   1.02    1.03  NA  NA            2000-04-01      1.64     1.63      1.64
# 3            2000-05-01    1.04   1.03    1.03  NA  NA            2000-05-01      1.65     1.64        NA
# 4            2000-06-01    1.04   1.03    1.03  NA  NA            2000-07-01      1.65     1.64      1.65
```

Comment: Why is the CSV code unusable?  I mostly just copied and cut it from the CSV file.  Also, the data you present isn't how it's supposed to go.  When I print the variable you've called `dat` I should get a different table.  I'll edit the original post to show how it should be.

Comment: well I didn't really try it, but you can use this on your data anyway. @Addem see edit

Comment: So there are some nice things in your code that I hadn't seen before that definitely help with the formatting issues, so thank you.  However, I'm still unsure of how to solve my biggest problem, which is with deleting appropriate parts of the data.  For instance, I would want to be able to delete the third row of the second group of data because it has an NA value.  Then I would want to delete the same date for the first group of values.  Then I'd also like to delete the fourth date of the first group because it contains a date, 2000-06-01, which the other doesn't have.

Comment: ... Er, nevermind, totally forgot that you told me how to store data frames as lists.

Comment: you can't just delete the third row of the second group. you would either have to delete the entire row, or change the second group third row to NA `dat[3, 9:12] <- NA` or whatever the proper indices are. then you can check to see if `Date == Date.1` and if it doesnt, then set `Date <- NA`